# Как изменить содержимое canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, background

На сайте есть светлая и темная тема. Для каждой срабатывает свой фон. Для светлой 
используется Trianglify.js и подобный метод вставки(фиксированный, не создавать через js)

```
<canvas id='c' style='margin-top:52px;margin-bottom:52px;height: calc(100% - 104px);width: 100%;background:#282c34;z-index: -50;'></canvas>
```

и простейший механизм вставки

```
  var pattern = Trianglify({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    });
```

как поместить изображение pattern  в canvas (без добавления ребенка)

Comment: я ничего не понял

Comment: надо к существующему объекту добавить pattern (заменить)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо было чуть чуть почитать [доки](http://qrohlf.com/trianglify/)

```js
function newTheme(){
  var pattern = Trianglify({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
  });

  pattern.canvas(document.getElementById('c'));
}

newTheme();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trianglify/2.0.0/trianglify.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="newTheme()">new theme</button>
<canvas id='c' style='margin-top:52px;margin-bottom:52px;height: calc(100% - 104px);width: 100%;background:#282c34;z-index: -50;'></canvas>
```

Comment: еще такой вопрос...там местами полоски (артефакты) возникают...почему?

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев а это уже к автору =), такое не супер сложно и самому нарисовать, и не будет артефактов =)

Comment: тут они как-то это исправили https://codepen.io/nodws/pen/YPgZao?editors=1010 в чем суть ?

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев там не используется канва, соответственно картинку рендерит браузер, а не алгоритм, который рисует на канве(из либы)

Comment: Но без этой либы тот алгоритм не работает

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев там должно быть как минимум 2 алгоритма, один который строит триангуляцию, второй, который её рисует

Answer (score 0):

Какой-то у вас не правильный canvas. Перепишите инлайновый стили в нормальный css подключаемый фаил.

```css
#c {
  margin-top: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 52px;
  height: calc(100% - 104px);
  width: 100%;
  background: #282c34;
  z-index: -50;
}

#c.activeLight{
 background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="activeLight" id="c"></canvas>
```

Если я правильно понял задачу, то это самое простое решение